# TeXLive Utility Not Updating multicol package

Tags: texlive, updating

According to http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol, the latest multicol package is `1.8g 2014-08-24`. After updating *all* packages via the `TeXLive Utility`:

[image]

I still only have the `2014/04/23 v1.8e` version.

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
multicol.sty    2014/04/23 v1.8e multicolumn formatting (FMi)
```

Is there a problem with some configuration files on my end or some issue with the TeXLive Utility?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the catalogue is wrong. I also get the same version as you do. No, it is stranger than that. Look in the DTX, it doe say `1.8g`!

Comment: I've send a not to the TeX Live mailinglist

Comment: @daleif 1.8g is on ctan but it's part of tools so the normal system is it goes to ctan, Heiko repackages and makes hyerlinked doc in latex-tds, texlive team takle that and update their data texlive mirrors pick up that, users get an update.... and it takes time and volunteer labour at each stage...

Comment: This is a snapshot of the current repository, which shows `multicol` has not yet been updated: http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/source/latex/tools/ This might be the problem: `multicol` is part of the `tools` TL-package, so it's possible that the change went unnoticed.

Comment: the change was uploaded to ctan with "no overall change" where the form asks for version number.  but it also says "multicol fix -- issue reported on stack exchange".  istm (and to petra, who installed the upload) that the version number _should_ be 1.8g.  ... so i guess i need to go and nag frank mittelbach.  (it's also possible that i need to prompt tex live, too.)

Comment: @davidcarlisle the "normal system" includes the ctan team announcing the change, and updating the catalogue.  the latter _did_ happen, but there was no announcement because of the prominent "no overall change" in the upload form.  i have mailed frank to ask what we (ctan) should do.

Comment: @wasteofspace there was an announcement and that clearly said multicol and varioref has been updated (my note "no overall change" was a misunderstanding and to my knowledge never made it in any announcement! so I wonder why you know about it (unless you are somebody I know hiding behind this name :-) ... Anyway both Karl and Heiko are aware of that update but as David says this is a manual effort

Comment: Closing question as this package got updated today -- all is good now.

Comment: Problem is now resolved via TeXLive update.